# MonkeyRunner with Robotframework

Tags: android, automation, monkeyrunner, sikuli, robotframework

I am planning to use monkeyrunner scripts to do automated test cases and I want to use robotframework(I am not interested in robotium). 
I saw an excellent tutorial for automating sikuli scripts with robotframework at
http://blog.mykhailo.com/2011/02/how-to-sikuli-and-robot-framework.html

Is there any way to do similar thing, with robotframework and monkeyrunner?

Here is my sample monkeyrunner script,this executes correctly when invoked with monkeyrunner.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

def testCase() :
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    result2 = device.takeSnapshot()
    # Writes the screenshot to a file
    result2.writeToFile("scr.png","png")

def my_keyword():
    print 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testCase()
```

I want to invoke the same with roboframework. and I am trying the following. I am not sure whether the following invocation is correct or not, I simply copied from sikuli automation example and modified it.

```
monkey_jar=/home/user/android-sdks/tools/lib/monkeyrunner.jar
guava_jar=/home/user/android-sdks/tools/lib/guavalib.jar
java -cp "robotframework-2.7.4.jar:$monkey_jar:$guava_jar" -Dpython.path="/home/user/android-sdks/tools/lib/" \
org.robotframework.RobotFramework --pythonpath=./  --outputdir=results --loglevel=TRACE $1
```

When I do this, I am getting the following error.

```
 Importing test library 'MyLibrary' failed: NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at MyLibrary$py.f$0(/home/user/automation/DemoScripts/MyLibrary.py:9)
    at MyLibrary$py.call_function(/home/user/automation/DemoScripts/MyLibrary.py)
    at robot.utils.importer$py._import$13(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py:154)
    at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py)
    at robot.utils.importer$py.import_$28(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py:241)
    at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py)
    at robot.utils.importer$py._import_class_or_module$4(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py:67)
    at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py)
    at robot.utils.importer$py.import_class_or_module$3(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py:64)
    at robot.utils.importer$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/importer.py)
    at robot.run$py.main$3(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/run.py:367)
    at robot.run$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/run.py)
    at robot.utils.application$py._execute$10(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/application.py:87)
    at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/application.py)
    at robot.utils.application$py.execute_cli$5(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/application.py:45)
    at robot.utils.application$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/utils/application.py)
    at robot.run$py.run_cli$6(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/run.py:396)
    at robot.run$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/run.py)
    at robot.jarrunner$py._run$3(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/jarrunner.py:60)
    at robot.jarrunner$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/jarrunner.py)
    at robot.jarrunner$py.run$2(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/jarrunner.py:53)
    at robot.jarrunner$py.call_function(/Users/jmalinen/Documents/workspace/robot/tmp-jar-dir/Lib/robot/jarrunner.py)
    at org.robotframework.RobotFramework.run(RobotFramework.java:62)
    at org.robotframework.RobotFramework.main(RobotFramework.java:37)
PYTHONPATH:
  /home/user/automation/DemoScripts
  /home/user/automation/DemoScripts/robotframework-2.7.4.jar/Lib/robot/libraries
  /home/user/automation/DemoScripts/robotframework-2.7.4.jar/Lib
  /home/user/android-sdks/tools/lib/
  /home/user/automation/DemoScripts/Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
  .
  /home/user/automation/DemoScripts
CLASSPATH:
  robotframework-2.7.4.jar
  /home/user/android-sdks/tools/lib/monkeyrunner.jar
  /home/user/android-sdks/tools/lib/guavalib.jar
==============================================================================
```

I believe that executing monkeyrunner test  cases along with roboframework is quite possible.

Any inputs?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the answer but, I'm interested in it and the down vote seems silly so +1 to restore the natural balance of the Androidverse.

Comment: Thank you. I added some more details with the post. I hope someone will provide inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after trying for few days, I found that it is possible to use MonkeyRunner scripts with Robotframework.

In short, you can use the folllowing to launch robotframework along with monkeyrunner.

```
export cpath=$(echo libs/*.jar | tr ' ' ':')
java   -Dpython.path=$cpath -jar robotframework-2.7.4.jar robo-tests.txt
```

But only problem was, monkeyrunner's main was not called, thus not initializing the ChimpChat object, which results in a null pointer exception. I fixed that in MonkeyRunner.java, and created a new monkeyrunner.jar. With this, I am able to run monkeyrunner scripts from roboframework. I will try to create a step by step tutorial and post it.

Answer (score 2):

@jollychang  do this way

add this to file MonkeyRunner.java

```
   if(chimpchat == null) {
        Map<String, String> chimp_options = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        chimp_options.put("backend", "adb");
        chimpchat = ChimpChat.getInstance(chimp_options);
        MonkeyRunner.setChimpChat(chimpchat);
    }
```

before:

```
    JythonUtils.convertDocAnnotationsForClass(MonkeyRunner.class, dict);
```

then make a new monkeyrunner.jar;

need some others jar like this:
[image: Libraries]

use the new monkeyrunner.jar  instead of the old one.

at last:  run robot with the command:

in my computer use this:

java   -cp /Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/chimpchat.jar:/Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/ddmlib.jar:/Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/guavalib.jar:/Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/monkeyrunner.jar:/Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib/sdklib.jar:/Users/komejun/Downloads/robotframework-2.7.5.jar -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir="/Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools" -Djava.library.path="/Users/komejun/Documents/devtool/android/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/lib" org.robotframework.RobotFramework a.txt